# Error using SUM result in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sum, where-clause

I'm having some troubles using the result of the operation SUM, which is called "weight" inside the where clause. I'd appreciate your help. Here is the query:

```
SELECT o.reference
     , SUM(od.product_weight * od.product_quantity) weight
     , SUM(od.total_price_tax_incl) total_paid_products
     , d.price
     , o.module
     , rw.id_range_weight
  FROM ps_orders o
     , ps_order_detail od
     , ps_product p
     , ps_supplier s
     , ps_delivery d
     , ps_address a
     , ps_state state
     , ps_range_weight rw 
 WHERE o.id_order = od.id_order 
   AND p.id_product = od.product_id 
   AND s.id_supplier = p.id_supplier 
   AND o.id_address_delivery = a.id_address 
   AND a.id_state = state.id_state 
   AND d.id_zone = state.id_zone 
   AND d.id_range_weight = rw.id_range_weight
   AND rw.delimiter1 <= weight 
   AND weight < rw.delimiter2
   AND 5 = rw.id_carrier
   AND p.id_supplier = 1 
   AND YEAR(o.date_upd) = 2016 
   AND MONTH(o.date_upd) = 5 
   AND o.current_state IN(2,3,4,5,15,16) 
   AND o.module IN('paypal','redsys','bankwire')
 GROUP 
    BY o.reference 
 ORDER 
    BY o.date_upd DESC
```

The value "weight" into the WHERE clause doesn't have the SUM result, the value 0 always... if I replace weight for a number it works perfectly, example using 10 instead of weight:

[image: sql result]

Thank you guys for your time!

Comment: So what is the problem? What isn't working? How isn't it working?

Comment: Generally, non-aggregated columns in the SELECT clause should also be included in the GROUP BY clause. And please don't use archaic join syntax.

Comment: Hello @SamiKuhmonen, the result when I use "weight" in the where clause is the same as if I use "0" but weight value is never 0, it must be 10, and 1... I don't know why it doesn't keep the SUM value.

What's wrong with that syntax @Strawberry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, thanks to @scaisEdge for this

```
HAVING  rw.delimiter1 <= weight AND weight < rw.delimiter2
```

and also thanks to @Strawberry for letting me know that non-aggregated columns in the SELECT clause should also be included in the GROUP BY clause.

Here is the full query

```
SELECT o.reference
     , Sum(od.product_weight * od.product_quantity) AS weight
     , SUM(od.total_price_tax_incl) AS total_paid_products
     , d.price
     , o.module
     , rw.id_range_weight
  FROM ps_orders o
     , ps_order_detail od
     , ps_product p
     , ps_supplier s
     , ps_delivery d
     , ps_address a
     , ps_state state
     , ps_range_weight rw 
 WHERE o.id_order = od.id_order 
   AND p.id_product = od.product_id 
   AND s.id_supplier = p.id_supplier 
   AND o.id_address_delivery = a.id_address 
   AND a.id_state = state.id_state 
   AND d.id_zone = state.id_zone 
   AND d.id_range_weight = rw.id_range_weight
   AND 5 = rw.id_carrier
   AND p.id_supplier = 1 
   AND year(o.date_upd) = 2016 
   AND month(o.date_upd) = 5 
   AND (o.current_state = 2 
        OR o.current_state = 3 
        OR o.current_state = 4 
        OR o.current_state = 5 
        OR o.current_state = 15 
        OR o.current_state = 16) 
   AND (o.module = 'paypal' 
        OR o.module = 'redsys' 
        OR o.module = 'bankwire')
 GROUP 
    BY o.reference
     , rw.delimiter1
     , rw.delimiter2
HAVING rw.delimiter1 <= weight 
   AND weight < rw.delimiter2
 ORDER 
    BY o.date_upd desc
```

Thank you guys for your time.

Answer (score 2):

For aggregate function use having and not where

```
SELECT o.reference, Sum(od.product_weight * od.product_quantity) as weight,
SUM(od.total_price_tax_incl) as total_paid_products, d.price, o.module, rw.id_range_weight

FROM ps_orders o, ps_order_detail od, ps_product p, ps_supplier s, ps_delivery d, 
ps_address a, ps_state state, ps_range_weight rw 

WHERE o.id_order = od.id_order AND p.id_product = od.product_id AND 
s.id_supplier = p.id_supplier AND o.id_address_delivery = a.id_address 
AND a.id_state = state.id_state AND d.id_zone = state.id_zone 
AND d.id_range_weight = rw.id_range_weight

AND 5 = rw.id_carrier
AND p.id_supplier = 1 AND year(o.date_upd) = 2016 AND month(o.date_upd) = 5 
AND (o.current_state = 2 OR o.current_state = 3 OR o.current_state = 4 OR 
o.current_state = 5 OR o.current_state = 15 OR o.current_state = 16) 
AND (o.module = 'paypal' OR o.module = 'redsys' OR o.module = 'bankwire')

GROUP BY o.reference 

HAVING  rw.delimiter1 <= weight AND weight < rw.delimiter2

ORDER BY o.date_upd desc
```

Comment: Hello @scaisEdge, thanks for the answer but it gives me an error "Unknown column 'rw.delimiter1' in 'having clause'